# What is the point of "(new Image()).src" in an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML for the main logo in the corner of the IMDb website.

```
<a onclick="(new Image()).src='/rg/home/navbar/images/b.gif?link=%2F%3Fref_%3Dnv_home';" href="/?ref_=nv_home" id="home_img" class="navbarSprite home" title="Home"></a>
```

I don't understand the onclick event. What is that doing? It doesn't make sense to me to see image instantiation as an onclick event for an image.

Comment: Creating a new Image object and assigning it a `src` is a way to make an HTTP request, without anything else happening (although the real link target will be followed here, if they have not suppressed that in another way) – you could call it “poor man’s AJAX”, if you like. It’ll request an image (or anything else) from the server and transfer the value of the `link` parameter while doing so – for some kind of tracking or whatever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a tracking click.  Although it is creating an image, the sole purpose is to make an easy external request to the tracking URL to log the click (the image is never displayed on the page).  b.gif is not really a GIF file, but a server-side tracking script.

Comment: Oh, of course, I might've guessed. Seems obvious in retrospect. I've just never seen the source of the tracking click be an actual .gif. I mean I get that it isn't really a .gif, that the request will be redirected to a .php or something, but I'm more used to seeing it get sent to a .php in the first place.